# Query count weekly in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query on a model like this:

```
public function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS jumlah 
                               FROM penitipan 
                               WHERE YEARWEEK(time_in)=YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
                               GROUP BY YEARWEEK(time_in)')->result();
    return $query;
}
```

From the query if the counted row does not exist it will not print the number 0.

But when there is calculated data it displays the number. How to display the number 0 if the data is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce`, so if the value is null, you can use 0 instead:

```
public function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) AS jumlah FROM penitipan WHERE YEARWEEK(time_in)=YEARWEEK(NOW()) GROUP BY YEARWEEK(time_in)')->result();
    return $query;
}
```

The `COALESCE` function gets the first value that is not null, in your case, it will get the 0 if the data is missing

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't return 0, is there any other way than that?